# Formatting categorical variables in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet on phone inquiries that lists:
-Date of call
-County
-Type of caller (resident, medical, etc.)
-Inquiry Category (Health concern, water quality, etc.)

I am trying to make an interactive dashboard and use pivot tables to link all of the data together. The issue is that the Inquiry Category topic is broken up by multiple columns.

For example:
Call Inquiry
Date    | Health Concern? | Water Quality | Other | Type of Caller | County |
11/30   |  Yes            | No            | Yes   |  Resident      | Suffolk

I cannot link the call inquiry sections (as a combined section) with the other sections (Date, County, Type). Is there a way where I can simplify the call inquiries into one column?

The real data has 8 call inquiry categories, and for some calls, multiple categories were "Yes".

I thought about using a check-box system with each of the categories in each cell. However, I am not sure if that data will display well on a bar graph.

I can't create a call category and then just type in the type of call inquiry because if it is multiple categories, i.e. water quality and health concerns, it won't separate those into individual counts.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to normalise the table and create new rows for each row that has multiple categories. So transform something like

`Date, Health Concern | Water Quality | Other`

into a three entries like

```
Date, Health Concern
Date, Water Quality
Date, Other
```

How EXACTLY you can do this greatly depends on the EXACT data format of your input data. It will most likely be possible to do with Power Query in Excel, but the exact steps depend on your data structure.

You can edit your question and provide a sample, including headers, identifiers, and separators for columns and records.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74801361/formatting-categorical-variables-for-pivot-tables-and-linking-to-other-data-in-e I created this new question with the excel example in it.

Comment: You're not really good at following directions, are you? I asked you to edit your question, but instead you started a new one.